# Redirect to index page if user is not authenticated

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm using ember-cli-simple-auth with ember-cli-simple-auth-token:

```
"ember-cli-simple-auth": "^0.8.0",
"ember-cli-simple-auth-token": "^0.7.3"
```

And i already made all configurations with my server to receive the token if the credentials matches with some user in my database.

My doubt now is how can i force redirect if a user tries to access one page if is not log in?

I'm using the following:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {});
```

And this is causing a blank page if the user is not authenticated.. but the redirect doesn't happen.. Am i missing some config here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change [`authenticationRoute`](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/Configuration.html#property_authenticationRoute):

```
// config/environment.js
ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
  authenticationRoute: 'index' // or '/' or 'application'
};
```

Comment: the default is login??

Comment: Yes, it is default value for that property.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with Ember.